# making monsters and hero while monsters affected only by gravity and platforms

Tags: box2d

You see, the monsters in my game will always be on the same positions. But they will affect by gravity and the platforms so they will be on the platform exactly. When the player touches a monster he gets minus life and blinks. But that's not my problem. I want the hero never to actually collide with the monsters, The monsters will never collide with anything but platforms and bullets. Please just tell me what would be the way to do that, what body type should be the monster, etc..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look b2Filter. And setup monster's fixtures and hero's fixtures using maskBits and categoryBits so they never collide